# How to display .html page

Tags: php, html

I had a index.html page and index.php file are in the same folder .My folder name is Tester and also i had the sub domain with the same name. i am using the following URL www.Tester.hoster.com/ . My issue is, if i use the above link it directly show the .php file. how i display the .html page instead of .php page plz guide me thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Add this in your `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 1):

This is something that you need to update on your server. Depending on if you're using Windows ( IIS configurations should handle this ) or Linux (.htaccess should handle this)

.htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

You can also add more file names/extensions after index.html, they will be treated by priority in the order in which you list them.

Not sure about ISS, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to do it, URL Rewrite being a smart option.

A quick technique is to change the name of the index.php file to something else, say home.php.